# ¿Cómo hacer una interpolación en PHP con llaves pero un previo signo de dolar?

Tags: php, php7

Tengo un numero X (int) el cuál deseo colocar en interpolación, pero necesito que aparezca un dollar sign antes del numero, sin espacion tipo $1:

```
<?php
    $numero = 1;
    echo "Esta es la ${$n}a edición";
```

Pero al hacerlo de esa manera me marca el error:

Notice: Undefined variable: 1

Quiero suponer que debo escapar al carácter ¿Cómo se hace en este caso?, esta leyendo que con \ se puede, así como también di con Heredoc de PHP

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
    $numero = 1;
    echo "Esta es la \${$n}a edición";
```

Sabía que era algo así pero no recordaba exactamente